# Strange result from String.Split()

Tags: powershell

Why does the following result in an array with 7 elements with 5 blank? I'd expect only 2 elements.
Where are the 5 blank elements coming from?

```
$a = 'OU=RAH,OU=RAC'

$b = $a.Split('OU=')
$b.Count 
$b

<#

Outputs:

7



RAH,


RAC

#>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It splits the string for each character in the separator. So its splitting it on 'O', 'U' & '='.

As @mklement0 has commented, my earlier answer would not work in all cases. So here is an alternate way to get the expected items.

```
$a.Split(',') |% { $_.Split('=') |? { $_ -ne 'OU' } }
```

This code will split the string, first on `,` then each item will be split on `=` and ignore the items that are `OU`, eventually returning the expected values:

```
RAH
RAC
```

This will work even in case of:

```
$a = 'OU=FOO,OU=RAH,OU=RAC'
```

generating 3 items `FOO`, `RAH` & `RAC`

<del>To get only 2 string as expected you could use following line:
$a.Split('OU=', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
Which will give output as:
RAH,
RAC
And if you use (note the comma in the separator)
$a.Split(',OU=', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
you will get
RAH
RAC</del>

This is probably what you want. :)

Comment: @mklement0 You are right. I've updated my answer to make it more generic.

Answer (score 7):

In order **to split by *strings* (rather than a *set of characters*) and/or *regular expressions*, use PowerShell's `-split` operator**:

```bash
PS> ('OU=RAH,OU=RAC' -split ',?OU=') -ne ''  # parentheses not strictly needed
RAH
RAC
```

- **`-split` by default interprets its RHS as a [*regular expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)**, and `,?OU=` matches both `OU` by itself and `,OU`, resulting in the desired splitting, returning the tokens as an *array*.

  - For all features supported by `-split`, including *literal* string matching, limiting the number of tokens returned, and use of script blocks, see [`Get-Help about_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split).
- Since the input *starts* with a match, however, `-split` considers the first element of the split to be the *empty string*. By passing the resulting array of tokens to `-ne ''`, we filter out these empty strings.

---

By contrast, **in *Windows PowerShell*** use of the **.NET (FullCLR, up to 4.x) [`String.Split()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)**, as you've tried, works very differently:

```bash
'OU=RAH,OU=RAC'.Split('OU=')
```

`OU=` is **interpreted as an array of - literal - *characters*, *any* of which, *individually* acts as separator** - irrespective of the order in which the characters are specified. Leading, adjacent, and trailing separators are by default considered to separate empty tokens, so you get an array of *7* tokens:
`@( '', '', '', 'RAH,', '', '', 'RAC')`

Note to **PowerShell *Core*** users (PowerShell versions 6 and above):
The **.NET *Core* `String.Split()` method now *does* have a scalar `[string]` overload that looks for an [entire (literal) string as the separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_String_System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_), which PowerShell Core selects *by default***; to get the character-array behavior described, you must cast to `[char[]]` explicitly:
`'OU=RAH,OU=RAC'.Split([char[]] 'OU=')`

---

If you construct the `.Split()` method call carefully, you *can* specify *strings*, but note that you still don't get *regular-expression* support:

```bash
PS> 'OU=RAH,OU=RAC'.Split([string[]] 'OU=', 'RemoveEmptyEntries')
RAH,
RAC
```

works to split by *literal string* `OU=`, removing empty entries, but as you can see, that doesn't allow you to account for the `,`

You can take this further by specifying an *array* of strings to split by, which works in this simple case, but ultimately doesn't give you the same flexibility as the regular expressions that PowerShell's `-split` operator provides:

```bash
PS> 'OU=RAH,OU=RAC'.Split([string[]] ('OU=', ',OU='), 'RemoveEmptyEntries')
RAH
RAC
```

Note that specifying an (array of) strings requires the *2*-argument form of the method call, meaning you must also specify a [`System.StringSplitOptions` enumeration value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). Use `'None'` to not apply any options (as of this writing, the only true option that is supported is `'RemoveEmptyEntries'`, as used above).
(The type-safe way to specify option is to use, e.g., `[System.StringSplitOptions]::None`, however, passing the option name as a *string* is a convenient shortcut; e.g., `'None'`.)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Just realised it looks for strings on either side of 'O', 'U', and '='.
There are therefore 5 blank chars (in front of the first 'O', between 'O' and 'U', between 'U' and '=', between the second 'O' and 'U', between the second 'U' and '=').

Answer (score 1):

String.Split() is character oriented. It splits on `O`, `U`, `=` as three separate places.

Think of it as intending to be used for `1,2,3,4,5`. If you had `,2,3,4,` it would imply there were empty spaces at the start and end. If you had `1,2,,,5` it would imply two empty spaces in the middle.

You can see with something like:

```
PS C:\> $a = 'OU=RAH,OU=RAC'
PS C:\> $a.Split('RAH')
OU=


,OU=

C
```

The spaces are `R_A_H` and `R_A`. Split on the end of a string, it introduces blanks at the start/end.

PowerShell's `-split` operator is string oriented.

```
PS D:\t> $a = 'OU=RAH,OU=RAC'

PS D:\t> $a -split 'OU='

RAH,
RAC
```

You might do better to split on the comma, then replace out OU=, or vice versa, e.g.

```
PS D:\t> $a = 'OU=RAH,OU=RAC'

PS D:\t> $a.Replace('OU=','').Split(',')
RAH
RAC
```