# Powershell split not returning expected result

Tags: powershell, split, powershell-5.0, powershell-core, email-address

Powershell 5.1.1 returns an unexpected result when I use the split function on a string.

So for example:

```
"some_user@domain.s483.hgy.i.lo.uk".split("@domain.")[-1]
>> uk
```

I would expect to see `domain.hgy.i.lo.uk` and not `uk`!

Is this a bug or am I missing something here? This appears to work on later versions of powershell. Can someone explain?

Comment: Take a look at the result of just `"some_user@domain.s483.hgy.i.lo.uk".split("@domain.")` and then consider that [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split#System_String_Split_System_Char___) takes an array of characters on which any will cause a split, not an exact sequence of characters on which to split.

Comment: Use `-split` operator for this --> `('some_user@domain.s483.hgy.i.lo.uk' -split '@domain\.')[-1]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result from String.Split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414946/strange-result-from-string-split).  See the note in [@mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40415484/150605): "the .NET Core `String.Split()` method now _does_ have a scalar `[string]` overload that looks for an entire string as the separator, which PowerShell Core selects _by default_..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-split` operator as follows:

```
"some_user@domain.s483.hgy.i.lo.uk" -split [regex]::Escape("@domain.")
```

> ```
> some_user
> s483.hgy.i.lo.uk
> ```

If you insist upon the `Split()` method then use

```
 "some_user@domain.s483.hgy.i.lo.uk".Split([string[]]'@domain.',[System.StringSplitOptions]::None)
```

> ```
> some_user
> s483.hgy.i.lo.uk
> ```

The latter is based on familiarity with a list of the different sets of arguments that can be used with `Split()` method:

```
''.split
```

> ```
> OverloadDefinitions
> -------------------
> string[] Split(Params char[] separator)
> string[] Split(char[] separator, int count)
> string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)
> string[] Split(char[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)
> string[] Split(string[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)
> string[] Split(string[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split on the first character of `@domain.` but *without removing "domain."*, use the `-split` regex operator with a lookahead assertion instead:

```
("some_user@domain.s483.hgy.i.lo.uk" -split "@(?=domain\.)")[-1]
```

See [JosefZ's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236832/712649) for how to force PowerShell to pick the [correct `String.Split()` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_), although it won't help you preserve the `domain.` part

Answer (score 1):

Or replace everything before the "@" sign with nothing:

```
'some_user@domain.s483.hgy.i.lo.uk' -replace '.*@'

domain.s483.hgy.i.lo.uk
```